# Android Developer Notification For In App Billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Can any one provide complete documentation for auto renew subscription and update status on backend using android developer notification with pub/sub?

We have to do Monthly & Yearly auto renew in app purchase subscription. If we subscribe using app,then we are getting purchase token and updating on backend.I have some query for auto renew subscription.

Please check the same as below:

1.Do we need to check subscription status at the time subscription period over using cron job? If yes,do we need to pass same purchasetoken in Purchases.subscriptions: get api?

2.If we enable developer notification for real time update on server,then we are getting notification on server. It doesn't contain any purchase information or unique user id.

Please check the below documentation :
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications
Real-time developer notifications do not provide full information about the state of the subscription, such as whether the user is currently entitled to access subscription content. When you receive the token, you should always use the purchase token to query the Google Play Developer API to get the full information and update your backend with the user's current entitlement status.
-> Will we get purchase token from realtime developer notifications?

Comment: @IshaanJavali I have updated my question for the issue which we are facing. Can you check once again?

Comment: I see, but now the question is too broad. You should try to implement it and then come here if you have errors in your code or if something is not working. But now, you are asking multiple different questions without trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented with the help of the [official implementation](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples). I hope this helps.

Comment: @KishanSolanki thanks for reporting! It seems that the repo was changed, so I modified the link!

Comment: could you tell how did you implement RTDN in app. I have done the configuration part like creating topic and subscription on Pub/Sub api also gave the necessary permission, but how to listen for messages published on topics inside app?

Comment: @NadeemShaikh you can't implement it on client-side! You should listen to the Pub/Sub API messages on server-side! E.g. I used Firebase Cloud Functions.